# Unable to delete apps 'folder' on macbook

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

Unable to delete apps 'folder' on Macbook. The folder labelled 'Delete Me'. Tried the usual drag to bin, restart computer. Any ideas?

[image: Folder Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in the end. Open 'Terminal' and run the following commands. (Clicking enter after each command).

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true
killall Dock
```